# How to customize a RNN cell

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to implement a custom LSTM or GRU cell in TensorFlow (Python 3). For example, I want to scale the cell state signal from the cell at time step T before entering the cell at time step T+1. I've tried searching in TensorFlow documentation without a success.
Could you give me a hint?
Thank you.

**EDIT**
Having checked the answer given by [@vijay m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262174/effect-of-setting-sequence-length-on-the-returned-state-in-dynamic-rnn/50289099#50289099), I create my model as follows:

```
def dynamic_scale_RNN(x, timescale, seqlen, weights, biases, keep_prop):
    batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]

    # Unstack to get a list of 'n_steps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.unstack(x, max_seq_len, 1)
    timescale_unstack = tf.unstack(timescale, max_seq_len, 1)

    gru_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(n_hidden)

    #init_state has to be set to zero
    init_state = gru_cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)

    outputs = []
    # Create a loop of N LSTM cells, N = time_steps.
    for i in range(len(x)):
        output, state= tf.nn.static_rnn(gru_cell, [x[i]], dtype=tf.float32, initial_state= init_state)
        # copy the init_state with the new state
        mask = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(timescale_unstack[i],axis=1),[1,state[0].get_shape()[-1]])
        init_state = tf.multiply(state,mask)
        # init_state = state
        outputs.append(output)

    # Transform the output to [batch_size, time_steps, vector_size]        
    outputs = tf.transpose(tf.squeeze(tf.stack(outputs)), [1, 0, 2])
```

In the code above, timescale is a tensor of shape `[batch_size, sequence_length, 1]` and I want to scale the cell state using this tensor. Even though the code can run, it returns `nan` for cost function.
If I uncomment the line `init_state = state`, it works, but it won't scale the cell state.

My question, for now, is that: Why I get `nan` values for cost function?

Comment: Check part 3 of the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262174/effect-of-setting-sequence-length-on-the-returned-state-in-dynamic-rnn/50289099#50289099

Comment: @vijaym I adopted your method but I got `nan` for the cost function. Why is that possible?

Comment: My method just unrolls the rnn, the result should be same as the unrolled method implemented in TF as proved in the above link. So nan's should be a result of the scaling introduced, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I leave my answer here in case it can help someone.
The reason for 'nan' cost value is that the `init_state` is set too high. While I don't know the appropriate range for this value, I can observe that if I scale it by a small factor like 0.1, I don't see 'nan' anymore.